# Firebird connection with java

Tags: java, firebird, firebird2.1, jaybird

I have installed Firebird 2.1 on windows Xp and using firebirdsql.jdbc-2.1.6 driver to connect with java. Code:

```
Class.forName("org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver"); 

connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
    "jdbc:firebirdsql://localhost/3050//C:/firebird/database/EMPLOYEE.FDB", 
    "test","test");
```

I am getting following error:

```
Caused by: org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBSQLException: GDS Exception. 335544375.
unavailable database 
Reason: unavailable database at 
org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDataSource.getConnection(FBDataSource.java:122) at 
org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver.connect(FBDriver.java:140) at 
java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:525) at 
java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:171)
```

Please help.

Problem solved:
Actually I had problem with jar file that I got from

http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2

I downloaded jaybird-full-2.1.6.jar from firebird offical website and problem got solved.

Correct URL is

```
"jdbc:firebirdsql://localhost:3050/C:\\firebird\\database\\EMPLOYEE.FDB"
```

I tried this URL earlier also but it was not working beacuse of jar issue.

Comment: Reformatted code; please revert if incorrect.

Comment: Don't add a "Problem solved" section to the question, post it as an answer instead and accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen observes, your [Jaybird JDBC URL](http://www.firebirdsql.org/index.php?op=devel&sub=jdbc&id=faq#6) is incorrect. The syntax is `jdbc:firebirdsql:[host[/port]:]<database>`. You need a colon between the host/port and the database path. Perhaps something like this:

```
"jdbc:firebirdsql://localhost/3050:C:\\firebird\database\EMPLOYEE.FDB"
```

Oops, I left in the leading slashes; try this:

```
"jdbc:firebirdsql:localhost/3050:C:\\firebird\database\EMPLOYEE.FDB"
```

Addendum:  You might run through the [common errors](http://www.firebirdsql.org/index.php?op=devel&sub=jdbc&id=faq#20) list. Also, my firebird database files end in `.fdb`, but the FAQ mentions `.gdb`. It can't hurt to check.

Comment: I have tried all the options including url specified by you..nothing is working..

Comment: Is Firebird running on port 3050? Can you connect by any other means, e.g. isql or a GUI client?

Comment: I can connect with isql and flameRobin..it is running on 3050 port..I have tried creating a new database..switching off windows firewall..copying dll's in system 32 (as specified on firebird support group)..

Comment: @rakesh-nitj: Sorry, I'm running low on fresh ideas; more above.

Comment: @trashgod:tried .gdb databases as well..anyways posted this question in firebird-java-support group..thanks for your time and efforts!

Comment: @rakesh-nitj: I'd like to hear how the problem gets resolved.

Comment: @trashgod:Problem got solved. Please see the updates above. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: @rakesh-nitj: Thanks for updating your question.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen: Sorry about misspelling your name. :-)

Answer (score 3):

From https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/drivers_documentation/java/faq.html#pure-java-default

Default URL format:

```
"jdbc:firebirdsql://host[:port]/<database>"
```

Deprecated, but still supported legacy URL format:

```
"jdbc:firebirdsql:host[/port]:<database>"
```

Then, the correct URL should be:

```
"jdbc:firebirdsql://localhost:3050/C:/firebird/database/EMPLOYEE.FDB"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your URL is most likely broken for this driver.

Attach actual source to the jar and set a breakpoint in FBDataSource.getConnection(...) and see what values are actually present when the connection is attempted made.

Are you absolutely certain that the combination of a hostname with port agrees with a path to the FDB-file?

Comment: I am absolutley sure about connection parameters along with the path of FDB file.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation on this site:
http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/drivers_documentation/java/faq.html, item 3.1

It seems that after the [port], you must have an slash "/" or double slash "//" in case you would connect on a linux server.

Answer (score 0):

To connect to the database located on remote machine or cloud (linux) then use following link.

jdbc:firebirdsql:34.212.208.251/3050:/opt/app/db/sample_training.fdb

Answer (score 0):

You should try this one. It works for me on Windows.

```
jdbc:firebirdsql://localhost:3050/C:\firebird\database\EMPLOYEE.FDB
```

Also make sure you added an exception for port 3050 to the Firewall.

Answer (score 0):

Connection string example for Apache Tomcat `properties.xml` with specified IP, port, data base alias and encoding:

`<entry key="db.url">jdbc:firebirdsql:127.0.0.1/2222:my-db-alias?lc_ctype=WIN1251</entry>`